# Is there a better synonym to "non-intrusive"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

If you are a photographer, you may want to take your pictures in a way that doesn't influence the surroundings and the people around you. As a result, you stay merely an observer, not an off-camera character of your photos. You try not to attract too much attention, to take photos when people don't realise they are being photographed – they don't pose, they don't try to be likable and act and look as they usually do (but, of course, you take photos with their consent).

One would call them *candid* photos and your manner, for a lack of a better word, *non-intrusive*. How else could you say that? "Furtive(ly)", "clandestine(ly)" and such don't fit because they have negative undertones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call it "unobtrusive" or "discreet":

> Unobtrusive: Not conspicuous or attracting attention [Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unobtrusive)

> Discreet: Intentionally unobtrusive [Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discreet)

Comment: Or you can be a [fly on the wall](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fly_on_the_wall). A fly-on-the-wall photographer.